# Rails validate child before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have an usual nested model

```
class Parent
  has_one :child
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
end

class Child
  belongs_to :parent

  validate :name, :presence => true
end
```

If I try to save a child without a name, it is prohibited, but if I save the parent with the child nested, if ignores the validation.

I don't want to repeat my child validations with `:reject_if`.

How can I validate the child and, only if the child is valid, save the parent along with the child?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [`validates_associated`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated):

```
class Parent
  has_one :child
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
  validates_associated :child
end
```